# Cake PHP: undefined offset error

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

i am newbie with Cake PHP. I am trying to run application that I have downloaded recently but it doesn't work.

My debug.log file says:
    2012-07-31 12:31:47 Debug: Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 in  [C:\wamp\www\app\models\vwbrowse.php, line 78]

And my error.log file: 
    2012-07-31 12:31:47 Warning: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [C:\wamp\www\app\models\vwbrowse.php, line 78]

And finally this is function that causes problem:

```
function afterFind($results, $primary)
{
    if(!$primary) return $results;

    $ret = array();

    //we are primary and not part of an associated find
    if(!is_array($results)) //find first
    {
        $tables = array_keys($results);
        $record = array();
        foreach($tables as $table){
            $record = array_merge($record,$result[$table]);
        }
        $ret['Vwbrowse'] = $record;

    }else{ //merge all arrays if separated
        $tables = array_keys($results[0]);
        foreach($results as $result){
            $record['Vwbrowse'] = array();
            foreach($tables as $table){
                $record['Vwbrowse'] = array_merge($record['Vwbrowse'],$result[$table]);
            }
            $ret[] = $record;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

**This is line 78: $tables = array_keys($results[0]);
**

What is wrong? Thanks in advance for solution.

Comment: `$results` doesn't contain what you think it does.  `var_dump($results)` to see what it contains - I suspect it isn't a multidimensional array when you expect it to be.

Comment: `$results` is an array but it does not have an index as `0`. So please try using var_dump

Answer (score 2):

You're checking to see if `$results` *IS NOT* an array, then telling your script to perform an `array_keys()` on it. Does not compute.

Also, you're trying to access `$results[0]` without confirmation that the `0`th index exists.

Try this first:

```
if (array_key_exists(0, $results)) { ... }
```

Comment: Yep that's weird and will fail later, but what is failing for the OP now is the _other_ call to `array_keys($results[0])` in the `else` condition.

Comment: @Michael good eyes...I missed that. Edited the answer to reflect this new realization.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined index` error is stating that the index of the array, in your case `[0]` is undefined.

You are checking if `$results` is an array with `if (!is_array($results))`, but not if it has any data. Try changing it to `if (!is_array($results) || (count($results) == 0))`.